# Можно ли перемещать сам Canvas в модуле tkinter на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, клавиатура

Уточнение: мне нужно перемещать `Canvas`, а не объекты находящиеся в нем.

**main.py**:

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard

Game = Tk()
Game['bg'] = 'black'
c = Canvas()
c.place(x = 0, y = 0)

x_c = 0
y_c = 0
speed_c = -10

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('left') or keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        x_c += speed_c
        c.place(x = x_c, y = y_c)
            
    if keyboard.is_pressed('right') or keyboard.is_pressed('d'):
        x_c -= speed_c
        c.place(x = x_c, y = y_c)
            
    if keyboard.is_pressed('up') or keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
        y_c += speed_c
        c.place(x = x_c, y = y_c)
            
    if keyboard.is_pressed('down') or keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        y_c -= speed_c
        c.place(x = x_c, y = y_c)
```

Вроде всё хорошо, но когда в `Canvas`'е много объектов тормозит...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard

root = Tk()
root['bg'] = 'blue'

c = Canvas(root, width=48, heigh=48, bg="white")
c.place(x = 0, y = 0)

img = PhotoImage(file="lena-2.png")
c.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=img)

x_c = 0
y_c = 0
speed_c = -10

# - while True:
def some_time():                                                     # +++
    global x_c, y_c, speed_c, c
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed('left') or keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        x_c += speed_c
        c.place(x = x_c, y = y_c)
            
    if keyboard.is_pressed('right') or keyboard.is_pressed('d'):
        x_c -= speed_c
        c.place(x = x_c, y = y_c)
            
    if keyboard.is_pressed('up') or keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
        y_c += speed_c
        c.place(x = x_c, y = y_c)
            
    if keyboard.is_pressed('down') or keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        y_c -= speed_c
        c.place(x = x_c, y = y_c)


    c.after(30, some_time)                                            # +++
    
some_time()                                                           # +++

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**lena-2.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]